# My Input pipeline with tf.data is converting images to negetives. How can I stop it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, face-recognition

I am making a triplet producing tf.data pipeline and while testing each dataset, It is producing negative of images.

I did already tried to normalize the image, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

All code is provided in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lkit57a03/251cc96b87f40a78b725522552043498).

But here is the gist of what I am doing:

```
def _read_image_and_resize(self, same_img_1, same_img_2, diff_img_1): 
    target_size = [self.img_height, self.img_width]
    # read images from disk
    img1_file = tf.io.read_file(same_img_1)
    img2_file = tf.io.read_file(same_img_2)
    img3_file = tf.io.read_file(diff_img_1)

    img1 = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img1_file, channels=3)
    img2 = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img2_file, channels=3)
    img3 = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img3_file, channels=3)

    img1_resized = tf.image.resize_images(img1, target_size)
    img2_resized = tf.image.resize_images(img2, target_size)
    img3_resized = tf.image.resize_images(img3, target_size)

    return img1, img2, img3
```

And here is the [negative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y56hh.jpg) I get as well as the [positive result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7z9L.jpg) I want.